# 'get up to speed with' or 'get up to speed on'

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases, adjective-phrases

> A) We work to ensure that our technical staff are up to speed on new technologies.
>
> B) We work to ensure that our technical staff are up to speed with new technologies.
>
> C) We work to ensure that our technical staff are up to date on new technologies.
>
> D) We work to ensure that our technical staff are up to date with new technologies.

I saw all the four usages, maybe in my imagination, thus getting confused. Which one is the most appropriate?

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference all of the forms are used.  "On" sounds more normal to me than with, but either can be used.  Get up to speed is a little less formal than get up to date.  Also, get up to speed can refer to learning new subject matter, while get up to date refers to getting current on what's going on (which get up to speed can also mean).

Comment: You could also use *with respect to*, *in the matter of*, *as far as X is concerned*, and any number of other formulations . . .

Answer (score 2):

## ['Up to speed'](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/186147)

> *(a)* up to full or working speed; at or up to a necessary or expected level of performance, up to scratch; *(b)* (in extended use) fully informed, up to date.
>
> > 1974 *N.Y. Times* 15 Aug. 33/5
> >
> > > ‘To bring up to speed’ was used occasionally in the Watergate hearings, meaning ‘to brief’.

so it's technically a little different from '[up to date](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/220262)' (*not slow* versus *not old*) but they *can* be synonyms if you mean your techs are **fully informed** about new technologies. If you mean they are already **using** new technology ideally and require no further training, you would say 'up to speed'. If you mean they **have** state-of-the-art tech, you'd say 'up to date'.

Using 'on' could mean '**on the subject of**' and using 'with' could mean '**with regard to**'; both are usually synonyms. Similarly, both of them could mean '**using**' and are again usually synonyms.

**tl;dr**: If you mean your techs are knowledgable, they're all basically synonyms and choosing one comes down to whether you want to emphasize that they *work efficiently* ('up to speed') or that they are *fully aware of the latest developments* ('up to date').